# Determine the set of all positive integers $n$ for which $3^{n+1}$ divides $2^{3^n} +1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I have two questions:

1) Determine the set of all positive integers $n$ for which $3^{n+1}$ divides $2^{3^n} +1$.

2) Prove that $3^{n+2}$ does not divide $2^{3^n} +1$ for any positive integer $n$.

This is the question. I have no idea to answer this question. So I need hint or help. I tried it using theory of congruence, elementary algebra etc. But I can't proceed. Somebody help me
Thank you.